# Android : How to add an horizontal Recycler view as list item inside Recycler Grid view list?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, linearlayoutmanager

I have a Recycler list on which **Grid layout Manger** set. I want to add an horizontal list (**Linear Layout Manager**) after 4th position of Grid list as an list item. See iOS sample screen in attachment[image].

Please let me know any solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: you have to use different viewgroups  inside recyclerview
checkout reference - https://betterprogramming.pub/create-heterogeneous-views-using-recyclerview-in-android-e2ad626686f6